# Gradual refactoring of Javascript/Jquery file into ES6 modules

Tags: javascript, webpack, es6-module-loader

I am refactoring a extremely large javascript file into multiple files with es6 modules / webpack.  To start with, I am moving a single function out of giantFile.js into singleFunction.js, and then importing this new function file into index.js, which is the entry point for webpack to create bundle.js, which is then included in my template.html file as a script tag.  In my template file, I also include giantFile.js as a script tag, which calls the function in singleFunction.js.

Is it simply a case of getting the script's imported in the correct order, or am i mistaken in my understanding of how giantFile.js can access the newly created modules.

Currently, within the console, when I type singleFunction(), i receive 'is not defined' error message', and so it would be good to check my understanding is correct of how I can use modules before further debugging.  If anyone can point me towards some good resources on refactoring front end javascript and best practives that would be much appreciated too. Many thanks.

in singleFunction.js

```
`export default function singleFunction() {...}`
```

in index.js

```
import singleFunction from './components/singleFunction'
```

in template.html

```
<script src="/frontendHotness/components/singleFunction.js"></script>
<script src="/unstructuredMess/js/giantFile.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

The webpack compiled version of your `giantFile.js` should still be your application's entry point and the only file that is embedded in your HTML file using the `<script>` tag.

During your refactoring, you should gradually move well-encapsulated bits of functionality into separate files, or modules. Those modules `export` the functionality, to be used by dependent modules.

Your parent module, in this case `giantFile.js` can now `import` the different modules it depends on. These dependencies will be resolved by webpack, which moves your parent module together with all its dependencies into one JavaScript file that you can load from your HTML page.

Note that this dependency tree can be arbitrarily deep - your submodules can itself depend on other modules. You should however ensure that your modules encapsulate the functionality to do one particular job while being loosely coupled with other modules. Also avoid circular dependencies.

Comment: Thanks for your response TimoSta.  However giantFile.js contains variables that are served up in the jinja template on the page, and I don't seem to be able to access these variables if I put the whole of giantFile.js through webpack..

Comment: One big advantage of ES6 modules is that their internal variables do *not* pollute the global state, and for this reason are not accessible from anywhere outside of the module, unless they have specifically been declared exports of the module. While I personally have never worked with Jinja, a google search for 'Jinja Webpack' results e.g. in [this npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jinja-loader). Maybe they offer a good approach to your problem?